# Xamarin forms listview "null"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I need to fill simple ListView with data, but listView is still null and i dont know why.
Code (xaml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SecuKey"
         x:Class="SecuKey.TransactionViewController">
<ListView x:Name="MainListView"  
         HasUnevenRows="True"  >  
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
       <DataTemplate>  
           <ViewCell>  
               <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">  
                   <Label Text="{Binding Name}" />  
               </StackLayout>  
           </ViewCell>  
       </DataTemplate>  
   </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
 </ListView>  
</ContentPage>
```

and c#:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SecuKey.Controllers.ViewControllers;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace SecuKey
{

public class ListViewTemplate
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

}
   
public partial class TransactionViewController : ContentPage
{
    public TransactionViewController()
    {
        // Just for test
        MainListView.ItemsSource = new List<ListViewTemplate> {
        new ListViewTemplate
            {
            Name = "Xamarin.Forms",
           },
           new ListViewTemplate
           {
               Name = "Android",
            },
            new ListViewTemplate
            {
                Name = "IOS",
           },
           new ListViewTemplate
           {
               Name = "Windows",
           }
       };
    }
 }
```

problem is here: MainListView.ItemsSource = new List {} becouse MainListView is null... Any advice please? I followed a tutorial and there isnt something more..

Thank you

Comment: i forgot: InitializeComponent();

Comment: It works fine on my side . You could clean the folder `bin` and `obj` , then clean and rebuild the project .

Answer (score -1):

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        List<ListViewTemplate> lists = new List<ListViewTemplate>();
        string[] N1 = { "Android", "Ios", "Windows" };
        for(int j=0;j< N1.Length; j++)
        {
            ListViewTemplate listView = new ListViewTemplate();
            listView.Name = N1[j];
            lists.Add(listView);
        }
        MainListView.ItemsSource = lists;
    }
```